# How to reassemble command line string using Boost Program Options?

Tags: c++, boost-program-options

- I parsed command line using Boost Program Options [as usual](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html). `po::command_line_parser` populated `po::variables_map vm`.
- I changed some values in `po::variables_map` like this:

  `vm.at(option).value() = val;`
- Now I need to reassemble modified command line string from `po::variables_map`. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Program Options `po:variables_map vm` has type:
`std::map<std::string, variable_value>`

`variable_value` stores value in boost::**any** v;
Usage of boost::any influences the solution:

```
string ProgramOptions::getCommandLine()
{
    using boost::any_cast;
    ostringstream cmdLine;
    for (auto i : _vm)
    {
        string dashForm = i.first.length() == 1 ? "-" : "--";
        cmdLine << dashForm << i.first << " ";
        boost::any value(i.second.value());
        if (auto *const v = any_cast<int>(&value))
            cmdLine << *v;
        else if(auto* const v = any_cast<string>(&value))
            cmdLine << *v;
        cmdLine << " ";
    }
    return cmdLine.str();
}
```

Comment: You can use `if(auto *const asInt = any_cast<int>(&i.second))` rather than checking the type manually.